# why this javascript code generates same output

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let day = [];
let hours = [];

for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

  for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {

    hours[k] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25 + 20);

  }

  day[j] = hours;
  console.log(`day[${j}] ${day[j]}`);

}
console.log(`${day[0]}`)
console.log(`${day[1]}`)
console.log(`${day[2]}`)
```

Comment: `day[j] = hours;` This will only set the reference not the copy of hours array.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `let hours = [];` globally, along with telling JavaScript that `day[j] = hours;`, `day[j]` will be assigned with the memory location of the global `hours`. In order to avoid that, you can assign new memory location for each `hours` generated by declaring it in block scope.

```js
let day = [];


for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  let hours = [];
  for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
  
    hours[k] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25 + 20);
  }

  day[j] = hours;
  console.log(`day[${j}] ${day[j]}`);

}
console.log(`${day[0]}`)
console.log(`${day[1]}`)
console.log(`${day[2]}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per `day[j] = hours` line, all the values of `day` i.e. `day[0]`, `day[1]` and `day[2]` are referring to array `hours`.
In the last execution cycle of inner `for` loop, value of `hours` is set to [29,27,42]. Hence the output is same for all `day` values.

To have proper values for each `day` elements, modify the code as follows:

```
day[j] = [...hours]
```